# DNS advice / failover

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

We're registered our domain at Network Solutions.  They went down a month ago and our DNS was down.  We're trying to find a way to mitigate this issue.  Our domain stops resolving and we have to send our customers to our our IP address and then the SSL cert gives them a warning. In short, it's annoying.

Of course, we can move to Namecheap or Godaddy, but we would still run into this issue....the bottle neck.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please clarify the warning message?

Comment: It might be a good idea to setup your domain name with two or more DNS providers so that if one goes down, you'll still have one.

Comment: Just read this: http://blog.dephuedatadesign.com/failover-name-servers-for-reliability-and-uptime and follow the part of "further failover measures".  Basically, like Zoredache said

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to host your DNS with the registrar you use.  Registering the zone, and acting as the host for the zone are two separate services.  There are many services in the world you can pay for to host your zone, or act as secondaries for your zone.

For example one organization I know has their domain registered through Godaddy, and zone is primarily hosted on dyn.com, but they also have Godaddy's Premium DNS server so that Godaddy is a secondary for the zone as well.  Which means their zone is both on Godaddy, and Dyn.com systems.

Answer (score 0):

Run your own.  You'll learn a ton in the process.

Comment: Including learning that it may be better left to a third-party who dedicates themselves to running a good DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Possibly.  I've done it myself for a long time without issue.  That said, I'm currently using Route 53 for my new dayjob.  I like DNS, so that's my bias.  Running some web UI somewhere will not teach you very much.

Comment: SF is a site for sysadmins, so I don't think there's anything wrong with "*do it yourself*".  If all we do is advise people to outsource, what are we?  Running your whole DNS setup is probably not something you'd want to do on day one, but you could run a single DNS secondary on a custom VPS (say) with fairly small risk, and you would, as dmourati suggests, learn a bunch about how the DNS works in the process.